# w3m doesn't show me images on Ubuntu. How to fix it?

Tags: w3m

I've updated apt and installed both `w3m` and `w3m-img`:

```
$ apt install w3m-img
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
w3m is already the newest version (0.5.3-36build1).
w3m-img is already the newest version (0.5.3-36build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.

$ which w3m            
/usr/bin/w3m

$ which w3mimgdisplay
w3mimgdisplay not found

$ which w3m-img                         
w3m-img not found

$ ls -la /usr/lib/w3m/w3mimgdisplay                          
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root video 26640 Feb  5  2018 /usr/lib/w3m/w3mimgdisplay
```

When I call: `w3m https://google.com` I don't see any images. How to fix it?
I tried it in Tilix and in gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2):

First of all [w3m-img](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/w3m-img) package provides

> inline image extension support utilities for w3m

so it does not have [separate executable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/w3m-img/filelist).

Then visit web-site with inline images like

```
w3m http://w3m.sourceforge.net
```

and you will get something like

> [image: w3m.sourceforge.net page]

---

Note: it may not work on text TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) inside VirtualBox - I have seen this problem.

Comment: I use Tilix as a terminal. Could this be a root of the problem?

Comment: Also I tried gnome-terminal. Images don't show in both cases.

Comment: For me Tilix and GNOME Terminal do not work. But I see that it works with `xterm`, `mate-terminal`, `konsole` and plain dumb tty.

Comment: This worked for me on st with [w3m patch](https://st.suckless.org/patches/w3m/)